# Call to a member function sendResponse() in magento 2 dirty play ground file

Tags: magento2

when I execute dirty play ground file in magento 2 I got the following error.

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function sendResponse() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 259**

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
)
{
    $this->_response = $response;
}
```

By adding above code in constructor this issue is resolved